# Is there any npm package that can show json schema in table?

Tags: javascript, json, npm, html-table, jsonschema

I've found a lot of npm packages such as x-render, react-jsonschema-form that can help to make form, but I wanna edit the data in a table ui. The example is given as blew:

```
  {
    $schema: 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#',
    title: 'json schema',
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      taskId: {
        type: 'string',
        title: 'taskId',
      },
      description: {
        type: 'string',
        title: 'description',
      }
    },
    required: ['taskId'],
  }
```

The UI is [image: here]

If the image is broken,just like this one:

```
title       |  type  | description  |  required
taskId      | string | xxxxxxxxxxx  |   true
description | string | xxxxxxxxxxx  |   false
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your requirements, you want a npm package that can renders a json into a table, and lets you edit it via an UI. Is that correct?

If so, give it a check to SlateJs, more specifically this example
https://www.slatejs.org/examples/tables

And as it states there, you can add complex functions if needed

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I looked at the slatejs implementation. 

I was hoping to create a table based on jsonschema that supports editing rather than a form, but there are a lot of modifications to slatejs (such as adding support for array types), and what I was hoping for was an npm package that supports quick builds.

In the end, thank you very much for your solution!